# Load images from folder with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dspace

i am new in QT and i want to display a lot of images, and be able to load them from a folder, i have a code for only one image, it worked fine but want to have the same result  for many images , here is my code :

```
 QString imagePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            tr("Open File"),
            "",
            tr("JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG (*.png);; BMP (*.bmp)" )
            );
imageObject = new QImage();
imageObject->load(imagePath);
image = QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(image);
scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Comment: try using code-brackets to make it readable :)

Comment: Use **QStringList QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(...)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the open folder, here just snipsets :

```
const QString folderPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Image folder"));
if(!folderPath.isEmpty())
{
    QDir dir(folderPath);
    QStringList filter;
    filter << QLatin1String("*.png");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.jpeg");
    filter << QLatin1String("*.jpg");
    dir.setNameFilters(filter);
    QFileInfoList filelistinfo = dir.entryInfoList();
    QStringList fileList;
    foreach (const QFileInfo &fileinfo, filelistinfo) {
        QString imageFile = fileinfo.absoluteFilePath();
        //imageFile is the image path, just put your load image code here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it is very helpful, however can ' t access to images ??

Comment: What do you mean can't access to images?